# Turn 3 dimensional goupedby dataframe into a barchart differentiated by color based on one of the columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

My original data looks something like this:

```
CREATION TIME   Type
3-2 21:00       0
3-2 21:00       0
3-2 22:00       0
4-2 21:00       0
3-2 21:00       1
3-2 22:00       1
4-2 22:00       1
3-2 21:00       2
4-2 22:00       2
4-2 22:00       2
```

While this is the resulting grouped data I have

```
Type    Day    Hour
0       3    21    2
             22    1
        4    21    1
1       3    21    1
             22    1
        4    22    1
2       3    21    1
        4    22    2
```

Imagine this being knocks on my front, backdoor and side door. Where 0 is front and 1 the backdoor and 2 being a side door. And it shows me the amount of knocks on each door per day and hour. It always displays the sum at the right

I want this data now to be shown in a barchart where data from the same day and hour gets stacked upon of each other just havin different color based on the type they are

[image: Example of how it should look in the end]

This represents of what I am looking for. I was playing around with matplotlib but I just cant seem to do it.
Hope someone can help

Edit:
Here my groupby code

```
time_data_station1 = df.groupby([df["Type"], df["CREATION TIME"].dt.day, df["CREATION TIME"].dt.hour]).size()
```

Comment: Please provide actual code so that people can see what's going on. Just initially you probably need to be using groupby or df[conditional] and seaborn since it makes stacking easier.

Comment: Added my groupby code, the result of my actual code has the same formatting like the one i created in the example just with way more days and times. Also there is an additional 3rd Type

Answer (score 1):

Okay this is what I did:

```css
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"Day":[3,3,3,4,4,4], "Hour":[21,21,22,21,21,22], "Type":[0,1,0,0,1,0], "Amount":[2,1,3,5,2,2]})

first = df[df["Type"] == 0].sort_values(["Day", "Hour"])
first.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
second = df[df["Type"] == 1].sort_values(["Day", "Hour"])
second.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
#third = df[df["Type"] == 2].sort_values(by=["Day", "Hour"])
#third.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
#fourth = df[df["Type"] == 3].sort_values(by=["Day", "Hour"])
#fourth.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
total = df.groupby(["Day","Hour"]).sum()
total.reset_index(inplace=True)

for i in [first,second]: # [first,second,third,fourth] modify this to increase the number of stacked elements
    ax = sns.barplot(x=total.index, y=total["Amount"], color="#09b0a8", alpha=0.3) #alpha makes color stacking easier
    for j in i.values:
        for num, val in enumerate(total.values):
            if val[0] == j[0] and val[1] == j[1]:
                total["Amount"].loc[num] = total["Amount"].loc[num] - j[3] #calculate height differential

plt.show()
```

This is a very manual way of solving the problem. There's definitely a library for this.

Comment: I appreciate the effort. Thing is I have 3 Types in total, So I dont think using Type==0 can split my data. I will have a look if I can change it somehow for me to work. I also edited the original question to reflect the data

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'knocks':[2,3,5,1,2,2,3,5,3]},
                 index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2],
                                                  [3.,3.,4.,3.,4.,4.,3.,3.,4.],
                                                  [21,22,21,21,21,22,21,22,21]]))


dfu=df.unstack(0)['knocks']
dfu.index = [f'Day {i} - Hour {j}' for i, j in dfu.index]

ax  = dfu.plot.bar(stacked=True, figsize=(12,8), rot=0)
ax.legend(title='Door');
ax.set_ylabel('Number of Knocks');
ax.set_title('Daily Hourly Knocks by Door');
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I edited my code to reflect my original dataframe. Can I still use MultiIndex on that?

Comment: @Pasgru Use `df.value_counts()` to create df.

Comment: This is far better than manually calculating the high differentials like I was attempting.

Comment: I will have a look at this later today will update you if it works :)

Comment: @ScottBoston I reposted my question with, what I hope is better insight in how I have my data. I really poorly framed my question in this post and already edited the original 6 times always adding more info that was relevant. Maybe you can have a look at it if you have time :)

Comment: @Pasgru You groupby creates a multiindex pd.Series... YOu can use the same code above just remove ['knocks'].